# Getting only 1000 pics from Google Picasa, I am using &showAll

Tags: android, picasa

I am trying to retrieve list of media from my Instant folder (auto backup). I have 10,000+ photos.

As suggested here:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/google-picasa-data-api/SW5T13KKneY/S5CrcfOt4kUJ , I need to append the URL with &showAll parameter, even with this I am unable to get the entire list. Here is the URL that I am using. Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/105627334328146XXXXXX/albumid/1000000446722XXX?prettyprint=true&showall
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `start-index` parameter, getting 1,000 items at a time.  It seems that 1,000 is the largest `max-results` you can have.  However, I'm currently having issues indexing past 10,002.

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/105627334328146XXXXXX/albumid/1000000446722XXX?prettyprint=true&showall&start-index=1001&max-results=1000
```

Edit:

This person shows how you can get the sub albums in the Instant Upload folder.

https://www.mail-archive.com/google-picasa-data-api@googlegroups.com/msg02665.html